# How can I build a twig template from a flat HTML file?

Tags: templates, twig

I need to create a theme that “extends” templates from an external CMS.

This CMS generates an HTML template with three placeholders:

- ###APPINCLUDEHEADER### : Placeholder for additional header content.
- ###APPINCLUDECONTENT### : Placeholder for the “main content”.
- ###APPINCLUDEFOOTER### : Placeholder for additional footer content.

I want to grab the template and replace the placeholders with Twig blocks. So, in the end, I can work on the template as it was created in Twig from the begining. Is it possible? How?

Please note also, the external template should be requested each time a user request the Twig template, as the external CMS content may change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that job by replacing placeholders by twig blocks:

<kbd>php</kbd>

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://example.com/cms/template.html");
$contents = str_replace("###APPINCLUDEHEADER###", "{% block header %}{% endblock %}", $contents);
$contents = str_replace("###APPINCLUDECONTENT###", "{% block content %}{% endblock %}", $contents);
$contents = str_replace("###APPINCLUDEFOOTER###", "{% block footer %}{% endblock %}", $contents);
file_put_contents("base.html.twig", $contents);
```

Then in your rendered view, you can use:

<kbd>layout.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block header %}
  {# your site's header #}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {# your site's body #}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
  {# your site's footer #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this will generate a new file "base.html.twig" every time the PHP is executed, but it doesn't solve the issue that the external template may change at any time. When the Twig template is rendered, the external template is not reconsidered. Can we have the PHP functionality executed in the Twig code? Or can a Twig function do the job?

Comment: If you call the php code I given every time, your base.html.twig file will be updated each time won't it? You eventually need to disable twig caching.